# Gulp 4 и инициализация после подключения

Tags: gulp

Добрый вечер. Решил перевести проект на Gulp 4 и сходу делема. Не срабатывает конструкция load. Как здесь это решается? Необходим require-dir, поскольку все модули разбросаны по файлам в /app

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    load = require('require-dir')('./app');

gulp.task('default', function (callback) {
    console.log('I was run');
    callback();
});
```

Вылетает с ошибкой 
`AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified`

Answer (score 2):

Хоть и прошло полгода, отвечу)

Данная ошибка появляется если вы вызываете таски так же, как вызывали в gulp 3.
Т.е. `gulp.task('default', ['task1', 'task2'])`
В gulp 4 нужно использовать либо `gulp.parallel`, либо `gulp.series`

Пример: 
`gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('task1', 'task2'))`

Но тут могут возникнуть проблемы с плагином "require-dir". В gulp 4 важен порядок, в котором были объявлены таски, и уже нельзя вызвать таск, который был объявлен после места вызова.

require-dir подключает файлы **в порядке их нахождения в директориях** и может случится так, что таск, вызывающий остальные таски, находится самым первым в директории. Результат -  `Task never defined`, остальные таски не будут видны.

Но если вы не собираетесь отступать от require-dir есть как минимум 1 решение:

Вместо `gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('task1', 'task2'))`, нужно писать

`gulp.task('default', function(cb) {
  gulp.parallel(
    'task1',
    'task2'
  )(cb)
});`

В этом случае не важно где расположены task1 и task 2, ошибки не будет.